# Converted LeadStatus based on Lead RecordType

Tags: apex

I have multiple record types on the Lead object.  I am trying to query and get the correct converted lead status, but since I have multiple converted statuses due to using lead processes I am having trouble getting the correct value.

This query returns the first record it finds, which **isn't** the one I want.  How can I get the correct MasterLabel based on the Lead Record Type?

```
SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Cant you filter by the label of the specific converted status you'd like to grab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relationship between LeadStatus and record type, so you will have maintain your own values map using Custom Metadata or Custom Settings.  For example, you could create a Custom Metadata object where one field is the record type name and another field is the converted status value, then pull these values into a Map when you need to do your processing.